# How to remove double quotes from array keys and values?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array where both the keys and values are wrapped in double quotes. Is there a way to remove the double quotes?

```
var_dump($my_array);

array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [""Phone number""]=>
    string(15) ""+1 555000555""
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [""Phone number""]=>
    string(15) ""+371 6665000559""
  }
}
```

I tried looping through every element and removing the quotes but I'm getting error undefined variable $new_array

```
foreach($my_array as $key => $value) {
   $new_array[] = str_replace('""', '', $key);
   $new_array[] = str_replace('""', '', $value);
}
```

Comment: how is this even possible .......

Comment: Variable is `$my_array` but you used `$myarray`

Comment: i find this extraordinary. Can you paste a `json_encode($my_array)`?

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs —```$my_array = [
 [ '"Phone number"' => '"+1 555000555"']
];```

Comment: This sounds like a problem that should be addressed at the point where the array is created rather than trying to fix it up afterwards.

Comment: You should define `$new_array` variable before loop or using `@$new_array[]` in loop

Comment: @Mohammad That is not needed in PHP. but the code is incorrect either way. https://3v4l.org/lUoua , it should be `$new_array[str_replace('""', '', $key)] = str_replace('""', '', $value);`

Answer (score 4):

Although it would be better to fix the source of the data, your code was almost there.  You should define any variables before you use them, and the way you do the replacements didn't add the item with the new key...

```
$new_array = [];
foreach($my_array as $key => $value) {
   $new_array[str_replace('""', '', $key)] = str_replace('""', '', $value);
}
```

Comment: You can use `@` before `$new_array` instead of defining it

Comment: @Mohammad I would rather add 1 line of code than use `@`, there are very few valid reasons (IMHO) to use `@`

Comment: I have one `if(strlen($which) > 1 && $which = @array_column($this->arguments, 'shortName', 'longName')[$which]);` I want `$which` to be null when not in arguments, so I don't care if it's undefined, and it saves me a `isset` check just to make it null any way,  [Github](https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/Cli)  I just wrote this and released it in just over 1 day :-D

Comment: Basically it converts `getArgument('help')` to `getArgument('h')` if it exists, if it doesn't it returns a default value, so the fact that it's undefined doesn't matter.  Because `$this->request[null]` will never exist.  Which is the only acceptable answer in that case.  Anyway its a `Cli` argument controller, very useful.  Other then that I agree it's best to avoid `@`

Answer (score 2):

I'd use trim

```
$test = array (
    0 => 
    array (
        "\"Phone number\"" => "\"+1 555000555\""
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
        "\"Phone number\"" => "\"+371 6665000559\""
    )
);


function trimQuotes(array $array){
    $o = [];
    foreach($array as $k=>$v){
        if(is_array($v)){
            $o[trim($k,"\"'")] = trimQuotes($v);
        }else{
            $o[trim($k,"\"'")] = trim($v,"\"'");
        }

    }
    return $o;
}

var_dump(trimQuotes($test));
```

This will remove both `"` and `'` that are leading and trailing, with no risk of removing other quotes in the string.

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Phone number"]=>
    string(12) "+1 555000555"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Phone number"]=>
    string(15) "+371 6665000559"
  }
}
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/aa67aea7119f323213b7e5ea808f3659178e9000)

The problem with a simple string replace method is that it will wipe all the quotes out in the string, regardless of where they are, that may or may not be an issue for you, though.

Comment: I have a 2 dimensional array so I get this error trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given. How can I make this work if this is my array? var_dump($test) gives this - array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [""Phone number""]=>
    string(15) ""+1 55526100718""
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [""Telefona numurs""]=>
    string(15) ""+1 55525151919""
  }
}

Comment: There I made it recursive, now it will do any number of nested arrays, simple

Comment: You also have the problem that if you have `""Phone number'""` which has a single quote in the actual text on the end of the string that this quote will be removed.  Using either replace or trim both have potential issues.

Comment: Granted but that it far less likely to happen, the only way to fix that is with `preg_replace("/^['\"]/", '', $string, 1)` and `preg_replace("/['\"]$/", '', $string, 1)`  Which is stupid in most cases. And even then if you have `"phone number'"` it's still going to remove the `'` if there is no double quote.  At some point you have to draw the line on edge cases.  Made me wonder I don't think I ever tested if this `preg_replace(["/^['\"]/", "/['\"]$/"], '', $string, 1)` resets the limit on each array item?  hmm

Comment: Not sure which is more common - say ""'Phone number'"" or ""Phone "" number"", as I only replace 2 double quotes next to each other.

Comment: But of course then you could have `""""""Phone number"""""` and it would only remove one set of quotes.  You can break any replacement code if you try hard enough.

Comment: Which is why you should fix the source of the problem rather than fudge the answer

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with that, but its not always possible to do.