# trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given - 2 dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a 2 dimensional array and I am trying to recreate an array, removing some quotes but I get an error

```
trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

Here is my array:

```
var_dump($my_array);

array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [""Phone number""]=>
    string(15) ""+1 55526100718""
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [""Phone number""]=>
    string(15) ""+1 55525151919""
  }
}
```

I am trying to recreate this array by looping through it's elements like this

```
$new_array = [];
foreach($my_array as $key => $value) {
   $new_array[trim($key,'"\'')] = trim($value,'"\'');
}
```

And I get an error - *trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given*

I also tried to put another array inside this array but then I only got a one dimensional array with only one item in it.

```
$new_array = [];
foreach($my_array as $value) {
    foreach ($value as $key => $val) {
        $result[trim($key,'"\'')] = trim($val,'"\'');
    }
}
```

But the result that I am expecting to get is this... (quotes removed from original array)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Phone number] => +1 55526100718
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Phone number] => +1 55525151919
        )

)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove double quotes from array keys and values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53047901/how-to-remove-double-quotes-from-array-keys-and-values)

Comment: If the answers in the duplicate indicated don't quit work, then please resolve it on that question rather than asking a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$new_array = [];
foreach($my_array as $k1 => $v1) {
    foreach ($v1 as $k2 => $v2) {
        $new_array[$k1][trim($k2, '"\'')] = trim($v2, '"\'');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an array within an array, try this:

```
$new_array = [];
foreach($my_array as $v) {
    foreach($v as $key => $value)
       $new_array[trim($key,'"\'')] = trim($value,'"\'');
}
```